# Large amount of DNS Queries

Tags: logging, dns, centos, soa

I want to switch to Dyndns.com for my DNS server, and I wanted to see how many DNS queries my server does. And I got very surprised.

At the moment, I have my own site, which is kind of inactive, and 3 other sites that have maybe 1000 visits each a month. Which is not much.

But anyway, I did turn on DNS logging on my server, and after 8 hours, there has been 28595 DNS queries performed.
Which will be 2.8 million in 1 month.

Half of them is AAAA lookups (I don't even have IPv6). Someone told me, you could increase the SOA to 1-2 hours, but mine is at 1 day at the moment, all zones on the domains is set to 4hours+, but 70% of them is set to 7 days in TTL.

Does anybody know, what the problem can be, and what I can do to solve it.

Best regards,
Lucas

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4074.txt) with some platforms including Windows 7 when the IPv6 fails it keeps retrying, the solution depends on your specific circumstances.